# Target tables in different schemas from store procedure but don't change code

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-schema

Please can any one advise if it is possible to have a stored procedure in the **[dbo]** schema select data from one table in one schema for users accessing via one database role and for it to select data from a like-named table in another schema for users accessing via another database role?

For example if I have three schemas in my database:

- **dbo**
- **green**
- **red**

I have two database logins **[RedLogin]** and **[GreenLogin]**. These connect to my database using respective database users **[RedUser]** and **[GreenUser]**. These users are members of the respective database roles **[RedRole]** and **[GreenRole]**.

- **[RedUser]** has a default schema of **[red]**.
- **[GreenUser]** has a default schema of **[green]**.
- **[RedRole]** has execute permission on **[dbo]** and select permission on
  the **[red]** schema.
- **[GreenRole]** has execute permission on **[dbo]** and select permission on
  the **[green]** schema.
- In the **[green]** schema I have a table called **[User]**.
- In the **[red]** schema I have a table called **[User]**.
- In the **[dbo]** schema I have a stored procedure called **[User_GetAll]**
  that runs.

**SELECT * FROM USER;**

What I would like is:

- For users who login with **[Redlogin]** and call the
  **[User_GetAll]** get all users from the **[red].[User]** table.
- For users who login with **[Greenlogin]** and call the
  **[User_GetAll]** get all users from the **[green].[User]** table.

So I have a question. For example:

-**[dbo]** schema in the past, I had 100 stored procedures. And now, I don't want to change code in stored procedure because It's so much, so How can I do to address the problem? Please help me.

....................................................................................

**Update:**

For simple example:

I have a schema **[dbo]**, and in that schema, I have created a stored procedure **dbo.GetAccount**:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetAccount
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM tblAccountNet
END
```

Then, I have created a schema **[ABC]** with user named **UserABC**.

Now, I would like to login with **UserABC** and execute **dbo.GetAccount** for schema **[ABC]** to get all user of it and don't want to change code of **dbo.GetAccount**. So, how can I do?

These are my ideas to resolve it:

1. Create another stored procedure in [dbo] schema, and use it to read all other procedure to make them execute against schema with user when login. Can I do that? So, how can I do that?
2. Create a stored procedure to change schema of all [dbo] procedure to [ABC]. Can I do that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your basic choice is to use dynamic SQL or to have a bunch of `if` statements for the different tables.

Comment: I don't fully understand, can you tell me solution details? thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet here would be to use dynamic SQL. That is something which allows you to pass string variables into a script which then gets executed against the SQL engine. For example, if you had variables `@dynamicsql` and `@usertype`, you would build a dyanmic SQL string like:

```
@dynamicsql = 'SELECT * FROM '+@usertype+'.tblAccountNet'
```

Then you would execute this code in a stored procedure using `EXEC(@dynamicsql)`. This would probably work, but it requires additional permissions for the user, and also opens you up to a whole world of security concerns, with the biggest one being SQL Injection attacks. So this would probably work, but it might be more trouble than it is worth.

http://xkcd.com/327/